# Why does my VPN stop working when I plug in my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, vpn

I have a VPN connection via Tunnelblick to work servers. Everything works fine up until the point I connect my iPhone to my MacBook, then the connection suddenly stops working, some internet pages load fine but I cannot reach the internal addresses of the VPN, the moment I unplug my phone everything starts working again.

Things I've checked:

- Phones hotspot is disabled
- Order of connections on System Settings is correct
- Output of VPN/Tunnelblick does not indicate/vary in any significant way

Any idea what could be going on?

Edit: Here are some screenshots of my configuration

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have also checked the logs of Tunnelblick after connecting the iPhone and there is no output. I did discover that if I set "turn off secondary interfaces" then no problem happens.

[image]
[image]

So I guess when my iPhone is connected via USB somehow the DNS flushes or is replaced at the OS level

Comment: Have you configured network access via the USB connection?

Comment: Well, I didn't configure anything, I can see the iPhone USB connection on the network settings, but it is turned off when the connection drops

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your network settings to your question. What happens when you reconnect your VPN in Tunnelblick? Did you contact Tunnelblick support?

Comment: Added screenshots and some more info while testing trying to get things to work. I discovered completely disabling other interfaces solves the issue, but I cannot use it, because I need my LAN connection to be active at the same time.

Comment: Having the same issue, though without solution.

Comment: The answer is to delete any virtual connections (they get created once you plug in an iPhone).

Comment: @OscarFranco could you add an answer with perhaps a screenshot/exact steps? I tried deleting virtual interfaces but the problem still persists. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For those facing similar issues. The issue was that when I plugged my iPhone into my computer virtual network connections would get created. Tunnelblick seems to kaputt itself with this edge case.

The solution was to delete all the virtual connections from system settings:

[image: Network settings]

Afterwards restarting Tunnelblick and connecting again would work. Although the connections get recreated every time and you have to delete them.